# Version: 1.4.5 ./a.out: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libcjson.so.1: undefined symbol: floor

Tags: linux, c++, c, json

I've an error related to cJSON.
I make and compile **Ultralightweight_cJSON** in Ubuntu 18.
cJSON working fine but just little issue happen.

When I use **cJSON_AddNumberToObject(fmt, "width", 1920);**
**cJSON_AddNumberToObject** related function then I got following error :

**Version: 1.4.5 ./a.out: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libcjson.so.1: undefined symbol: floor**

I also try to compile with **-lm** but still not work.
Kindly suggest me what I do for resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me.

Make sure you've actually installed it to your system:

1. `git clone https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON`
2. `cd cJSON && mkdir build && cd build`
3. `cmake ..`
4. `make`
5. `sudo make install` <- actually installs it
6. `sudo ldconfig` <- updates links to libraries (you probably need to do this)

Then simply compile a program, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cjson/cJSON.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cJSON *monitor = cJSON_CreateObject();

    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(monitor, "width", 1920);

    char *string = cJSON_Print(monitor);

    printf("%s\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

like this:

```
gcc example.c -o example.out -lcjson
```

And try running it:

```
./example.out
```

Gives me

```
{
    "width":    1920
}
```

Comment: Actually as per your given steps again I'm trying to install but currently give me an error : test.c:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `cJSON_AddNumberToObject'

and I check one more path : /usr/lib/ there are no libm.a or libm.so present.

Comment: `libm` should be located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and is provided by the `libc6` package. You could try `sudo apt install libc6`, but you probably already have it. You will again need to run `sudo ldconfig` afterwards.

Comment: Yes,its works. Using 'sudo ldconfig' and 'sudo apt install libc6'.
Thanks necklace.